# How can I tell if lack of memory is causing these crashes?

Tags: memory, administration

I have a tornado web server running a flask application that connects to a postgres 9.3 database on an ubuntu 12.04 box. The application has been crashing intermittently and I am trying to understand why. The customer service for my cloud provider (digital ocean) says:

> Many times, we see smaller sized droplets that run a full LAMP stack,
>   run out of memory due to the many processes that are running, that can
>   cause slow connections or services like Apache and MySQL crashing.

How can I investigate this hypothesis? Is there a way to see how much memory is being used at different times on the server? Are there logs that might point to why the application is crashing?

Comment: Depends on how the server is configured. If it's configured such that the OOM killer is enabled, you can use `dmesg` to see. If OOM killer is not enabled, the application will simply experience `malloc()` failures, upon which the only way to tell is if the application logs it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Munin to [monitor Postgres](http://highperfpostgres.com/guides/postgresql-monitoring-with-munin/) and other services. You can use monit to restart a service automatically when the load is too high.